# Unexpected token, expected , (8:21)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, blockchain

So I'm working with this code for a blockchain mining class

```
const Block = require('./Block');
class Blockchain{
    constructor(){
        this.chain = [Blockchain.genesis()];
    }
    addBlock({data}){
        const newBlock = Block.mineBlock([
            lastBlock: this.chain[this.chain.length-1],
            data
        ]);
        this.chain.push();
    }
}
module.exports = Blockchain;
```

And I keep getting this error `Unexpected token, expected , (8:21)`, for this line:

```
lastBlock: this.chain[this.chain.length-1],
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: That part looks like a mixture of object and array, which one do you want?

Comment: That's a normal syntax error as `[ key: value ]` is no proper JS syntax... You likely mean `{ key: value }`

Comment: I want the object, i also want it to like get the last block of the chain, which is what the code was for, this is a part of a course that im taking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using this

```
Block.mineBlock({
lastBlock: this.chain[this.chain.length-1],
data
})
```

Seems to me like you `key:value` pairs are not properly formatted..
The code in probably taking

```
lastBlock: this.chain[this.chain.length-1],
```

this above line as Key and is expecting a value from data

Comment: doesnt work, same error, does it have to do with  the possibility of passing the information maybe?

Comment: yes it could be maybe then ```Block.mineBlock()``` doesnt take a array may be try using { } instead of [ ]

Comment: Can you mark my solution as answer please it will helps me back as well :)